# Any alternative to hidden fields when updating from a viewmodel? I don't want to have all fields in the edit page

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I know there is a way to do this the "right" way, but for some reason I can't find an answer. I even saw on Microsofts guide that hidden fields are the way to go, but it feels "wrong".

I am finding my update works fine when I put all the hidden fields in the Edit form:

```
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.Organizations" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.Address" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.AlternateId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.Category" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.City" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.FriendlyPath" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.IsTop" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.Name" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.NextChildId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.RecoveryOverride" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.RowStatus" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.RowVersion" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.State" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.UseAppVersion" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrgUnits.ZipCode" />
```

But, that seems like a poor way to write code. I only want a few of the fields in this table to be editable.

Here is my controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("OrgUnits")] OrgUnitsViewModel orgUnitsViewModel)
    {
        id = Uri.UnescapeDataString(id);
        
        if (id != orgUnitsViewModel.OrgUnits.OrgUnitId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get org for the DbCatalog
                var org = await _opkCoreContext.Organizations.FindAsync(orgUnitsViewModel.OrgUnits.OrgId);
                _serverConnectionHelper.SetDatabaseConnectStringToSession(org.DbCatalog);

                _opkDataContext.Update(orgUnitsViewModel.OrgUnits);
                await _opkDataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!OrgUnitsExists(orgUnitsViewModel.OrgUnits.OrgUnitId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { currentSearchFilter = orgUnitsViewModel.OrgUnits.OrgUnitId });
        }
        return View(orgUnitsViewModel);
    }
```

Is this really how this is supposed to be done. I went the route of AutoMapper, but that was failing for me and I don't quite understand how to use it. Anyways, here is my error:

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

Hopefully one of you smart people out there know the answer. I am surprised I can't find anything on Google or SO because I know this is extremely common. It is just that hidden fleids seems so wrong because what if you miss one?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you going to do partial update?

Comment: I recommend you read [Ultimate Asp.Net Core 3 Web API](https://code-maze.com/ultimate-aspnet-core-3-web-api/) book. This is very effective book. One of the best books i've ever read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do following For partially update an entity:

If I don't want to send an entire model to action to change entire entity, I would make an endpoint(API action) that partially update entity and return success status code instead of View. I would use ajax request to the endpoint to change the entity without refreshing the page.

This is my code for partially updating a `Employee` entity:

Employee.cs

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Employee name is a required field.")]
    [MaxLength(30,ErrorMessage ="Maximum length for the Name is 30 chrachters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is a required field.")]
    public int Age{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position is a required field.")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length for the Position is 20 chrachters.")]
    public string Position { get; set; }


    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeeUpdateDto.cs

```cs
public class EmployeeUpdateDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee name is required")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length for the Name is 30 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(18, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Minimum age must be 18")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee position is required")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length for the Position is 20 characters")]
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs

```cs
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private IRepositoryManager _repository;
    private ILoggerManager _logger;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public EmployeesController(IRepositoryManager repository, ILoggerManager logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }


    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PartiallyUpdateEmployee(int id, JsonPatchDocument<EmployeeUpdateDto> employeePatches)
    {
        if (employeePatches is null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("JsonPatchDocument object sent from client is null");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var employeeEntity = await _repository.EmployeeRepository.GetEmployeeAsync(employeeId, trackChanges:true);
        if (employeeEntity null)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo($"Employee with id {id} doesn't exist in the database.");
            return NotFound();

        }

        var employeeUpdateDto = _mapper.Map<EmployeeUpdateDto>(employeeEntity);

        employeePatches.ApplyTo(employeeUpdateDto, ModelState);
        TryValidateModel(employeeUpdateDto);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _logger.LogError("invalid model state for the patch document");
            return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
        }

        _mapper.Map(employeeUpdateDto, employeeEntity);
        await _repository.SaveAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }

    //other action methods

}
```

You must send your request body in the following standard patch format (json):

```js
[ 
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "new_name": "new name" }, 
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/position" } 
]
```

That's it. the sample request above would change the Employee name to "new_name" and set the Position to its default value (in this case null).

**Above sample needs these prerequisites to work:**

[image]

- *Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch* to support `JsonPatchDocument` type.
- *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson* to support mapping request to `JsonPatchDocument<T>`. Configure this in `ConfigureServices()` method:

  services.AddControllersWithViews
  .AddNewtonsoftJson();
- *AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection* to map EmployeeUpdateDto to Employee. Add a mapping profile class and configure AutoMapper in `ConfigureServices()` method:

  ```
  services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
  ```

and

```cs
public class MappingpProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingpProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CompanyUpdateDto, Company>();
        CreateMap<CompanyCreationDto, Company>();

        CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
        CreateMap<EmployeeCreationDto, Employee>();
        CreateMap<EmployeeUpdateDto, Employee>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

In above code we use `CreateMap<EmployeeUpdateDto, Employee>().ReverseMap();` for our needs.

Comment: Thank you for the effort in your explanation. I will have to put some thought into this to figure it out. It involves a couple of libraries and ideas that I am not too familiar with.

Comment: Could you explain the Json part a bit? How does the View get this data back to the Controller?

Comment: Actually, thanks to your response it helped me understand mapping a bit better. I now have a class that only has the values I wish to update. Then in my controller I look up the original value from the database and build my smaller model. The smaller model is passed to my edit view. I can make my edits and then send those back to my save changes method in the controller. From there I look up the original model, update everything in the original to be the updated version from the view model (smaller model), then save the original. Now I just need to get AutoMapper in the mix and I am golden! TY

Comment: Friendly side note for you: you have a typo in "characters" in your Employee class message

Comment: "Could you explain the Json part a bit?", Do you still need demonstration? Do you mean request body?